# How do I sort an array filled with objects, based on two values of the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I've got an array populated with objects. These objects start with two values: `sort1` and `sort2`.

```
var arr_obj = [
    {
        sort1:'3000',
        sort2:'200',
        value:'Value1'
    },
     {
        sort1:'4000',
        sort2:'100',
        value:'Value2'
    },
     {
        sort1:'6000',
        sort2:'200',
        value:'Value3'
    },
     {
        sort1:'6000',
        sort2:'100',
        value:'Value4'
    },
     {
        sort1:'2000',
        sort2:'500',
        value:'Value5'
    }
];
```

How do I go about sorting the objects based on the values of `sort1` and `sort2`. `Sort1` is dominant and if two values have the same `sort1` value then the sort function should look at `sort2` to determine which one comes first.

So for my example array the output should become.

```
[
    {
        sort1:'2000',
        sort2:'500',
        value:'Value5'
    },
    {
        sort1:'3000',
        sort2:'200',
        value:'Value1'
    },
     {
        sort1:'4000',
        sort2:'100',
        value:'Value2'
    },
    {
        sort1:'6000',
        sort2:'100',
        value:'Value4'
    },
     {
        sort1:'6000',
        sort2:'200',
        value:'Value3'
    }     
];
```

I tried just using a simple `sort()` on the array, but this probably looks at the index not the first values.
Does anyone know how to get the requested output?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7npce5ab/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a compare function into the sort.

```
arr_obj.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a.sort1 === b.sort1) {
    return a.sort2 - b.sort2;
  }
  return a.sort1 - b.sort1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
arr_obj.sort(function(prev,next){
  if(prev.sort1 != next.sort1){
    return prev.sort1 > next.sort1;
  }else{
   return prev.sort2 > next.sort2;
  }
});
```